# Openshift pods crash

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes

I have created image locally (docker image)
and when i run image witg oc run AA --image=(docker image name).

It  runs and crashes after few seconds. There is no log in oc and docker.

Error in oc describe is crashloopbackoff

Comment: Do you get any interesting messages using ``oc events``? Do you see any extra messages if you use ``oc logs --previous``? have you looked at the logs for the deployment?

Comment: You can view the logs of a crashed docker container by using `docker ps -a` to get all containers. And then `docker logs $CRASHED_CONTAINER_ID`

Comment: I assume you're able to run it on docker? Can you show which is the user inside your container?

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending the minishift/openshift internal docker registry to the docker image name:

```
# e.g. get the registry address
$ minishift openshift registry
172.30.1.1:5000
$ oc run AA -i -t --image=172.30.1.1:5000/<project>/<docker image name>:<tag>
```